# Allow only numbers and forward slash in a HTML text box

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want a text with Date format . I am able to manage to get like 20/03/2020 but its accepting Characters as well

If I use /[^0-9]/gi then charters are removed immediately when pressed but forward slash also get removed (I need the forward slash).
If I use  /[^0-9][//]/gi then i get the forward slash but it's not restricting characters.

How can I fixed it

```
function restrictAlphas(e) {

            var invalidcharacters = /[^0-9][/\/]/gi;


            var xval = document.getElementById("idcrd").value;
            var length = xval.length;


            if (length<=10){
                if (invalidcharacters.test(xval)) {
                    newVal= xval.replace(invalidcharacters, "");
                    document.getElementById("idcrd").value = newVal;

                }
                else {
                    if ((length == 2 || length == 5)) {

                        document.getElementById("idcrd").value = xval + '/';
                    }
                }
        }




        }
```

HTML :

```
 <input type ="text"  name="crd" id="idcrd" maxlength="10" onkeyup="return restrictAlphas(event)"  />
```

Comment: You're probably much better off using the [date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) that HTML provides (`<input type="date" />`).

Comment: why not use input type date?

Comment: ``<input type="date" />`` will solve your problem.

Comment: I am using HTML and IE 11, So <input type="date"> doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **html5** `pattern` attribute. And use `[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` as the regex pattern to match the needed characters in this case.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text"  name="crd" id="idcrd" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Button">
</form>
```

Comment: Check your example again. It fails after the first set of numbers/slash.

Comment: You wanna use more than one forward slash?

Comment: You can't enter a date. You can only enter `02/` for example. Any more than that and your example fails.

Comment: Ok wait I'm updating it

Comment: @Andy You can try it again now.

Comment: *A* - it not prevent to write wrong format. only submit. *B* it allow things like `04444/07/3`. if go for it, it should be more like `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky I have updated it. It is more stable now.

Comment: Just a little more - the year should be 4 numbers. (for now the very correct date is rejected)

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky that is much better.

Comment: what is better? the requested format is `dd/mm/yyyy` which rejected now. you should do `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky is that a Javascript regex?

Comment: I mean no need to escape the `/`.

Comment: yes it is.. `\d` means number, and in the `{}` you put the number of repeating

Comment: so its mean 2 numbers, then slash, 2 numbers, slash, and 4 numbers (for the year)

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky wow man Thats cool! I've been missing that in most of my regex. I got a new skill woo.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function restrictAlphas(e) {
     e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[\D]/g, '').replace(/(\d{2})/, "$1/").replace(/(\d{2}\/\d{2})/, "$1/");
}
```

```html
 <input type ="text"  name="crd" id="idcrd" maxlength="10" oninput="restrictAlphas(event)"  />
```